# SQL: Add 1 (or N) to a given column of every row when the column is unique and sequential?

Tags: sql, sqlite, unique-constraint

I have an sqlite database with a table, let's call it `books`. The table has a column named `ordering` which is a UNIQUE integer column used as the default column for an ORDER BY clause.

When the user wants to change the ordering, my software presents them with a drag-n-drop interface that ultimately results in inserting a given row in between two other rows (ignoring end cases for now), and updating all subsequent rows.

My first step is to increment all the rows after where I want to insert it, so there's space in the sequence for the new item. The SQL looks like this:

`UPDATE menuitem SET ordering=ordering+1 WHERE ordering >= 3; # ordering=3 is where I want to insert the item`

I get the following error: `Error: column ordering is not unique`

I guess that because it's trying to update the rows one by one, and it can't handle the fact that there will be a split second when the previous row will equal the subsequent row. I'm surprised by that, as I thought it would be an atomic operation and it would only care about constraints once the query is complete.

Anyway, assuming that's the issue, I've tried (on a hunch) to run the update in reverse order, so it's updating the highest number first, and there will be no temporary conflicts. This seems fragile to me, but no luck anyway, no matter what I try:

```
sqlite> UPDATE menuitem SET ordering=ordering+1 WHERE ordering >= 3 ORDER BY ordering DESC;
Error: ORDER BY without LIMIT on UPDATE

sqlite> UPDATE menuitem SET ordering=ordering+1 WHERE ordering >= 3 ORDER BY ordering DESC LIMIT -1;
Error: column ordering is not unique

sqlite> UPDATE menuitem SET ordering=ordering+1 WHERE ordering >= 3 ORDER BY ordering LIMIT -1;
Error: column ordering is not unique
```

What gives? Do I have to remove the unique constraint? Is there a better way?

Comment: A heretic thought: just drop the UNIQUE constraint …

Comment: Yes, I'm usually not sorry to get rid of a database constraint -- seems like they get in the way as often as they help. Also seems a bit silly that database engines make such big deal about integrity and yet sometimes the simplest things are (needlessly?) difficult or impossible because of some constraint or other. Nevertheless, it's nice to have certainty that your data's intact, and useful to know if there's a standard way to achieve something.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by doing the update twice.  Here is an example:

```
update menuitem
    set ordering = -ordering
    where ordering >= 3; # ordering=3 is where I want to insert the item

insert new item here

update menuitem
    set ordering = (-ordering) + 1
    where ordering < 0;
```

Comment: Interesting and useful, thanks. Pity about the double-update, but it's a good solution.